# Symfony and Wkhtmltopdf : Error beyond 1000 pages

Tags: php, symfony, debian, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

With Symfony, KnpSnappy and Wkhtmltopdf, I can generale PDF ~800 pages. But > 1000 pages, I have this PHP error :

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException: "The process has been signaled with signal "11".

This error comes from the php function [proc_get_status](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php)

My phpinfo at very big values (memory limit, maximum execution time, etc.).

I tried with a blank PDF of 1300 pages and I immediately this error. So it's the page number that causes the error and not the content.

Can you help me ?
Thanks very much

Comment: php version? signal "11" is a segfault (PHP bug).

Comment: My my version of php is 7.1.21.

Comment: generally 1) don't try to do something like that sync but have worker doing it and 2) don't do it just in one run, but do it in bulks to free up resources in between.

Comment: How did you found out that it was php function proc_get_status?